# Matching mockito obj.getMethod().equals(x) within when() clause

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm in the process of writing a mocking layer on top of our existing Db api (it can't be changed sadly).  I'm envisioning mocks that are specific to certain table functions, initially - just concerned about table names.

```
when(mockDbApi.query(argThat(new TableNameMatcher("table1")))).thenReturn(result);
```

Where the query function takes an argument of QueryDescriptor.  My TableArgumentMatcher class is below:

```
public static class TableNameMatcher extends ArgumentMatcher<QueryDescriptor> {
    private String tableName;

    public TableNameMatcher(String tableName) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object argument) {
        if (argument instanceof QueryDescriptor) {
            QueryDescriptor qDescript = (QueryDescriptor) argument;
            return qDescript.getBaseTable().equals(tableName);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Trying this, I'm ending up with an exception dump of (the framework is being nice  and custom rendering the stack trace for me):

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
Misplaced argument matcher detected here:
at com.company.CommonsTestDb.mockQuery(CommonsTestDb.java:88)

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains(&quot;foo&quot;))
```

The CommonsTestDb line 88 is where I'm doing the same when() as I listed above.  Note that the code does compile cleanly and is not warning me of any type issues.

Thoughts? I see many examples of individuals being redirected to use the capturing capabilities and validate the match later however I don't think it's appropriate where as their may be multiple when clauses for various tables.

Thanks,

Comment: This should be `query(argThat(new TableNameMatcher("table1")))`, right?  Unclear how this would compile otherwise.

Comment: please post the whole stacktrace

Comment: Added, not sure if it'll be of any help as it's throwing the exception on the same line as the when() clause.

Comment: Corrected the query - initially typed in by hand instead of pasting and had dropped the argThat invocation.

Comment: That seems pretty reasonable so far. Can you please post more of your test class? Specifically I'd like to know how `mockDbApi` is populated, whether it's typed as an interface or a concrete class, and that `query` is `public`, non-`static`, and non-`final`. Also, please tell us if there is any code that uses mocks or matchers earlier in the method; matchers are stateful, so sometimes earlier lines can throw off Mockito in ways that misleadingly point to valid usage. Calling the method `Mockito.validateMockitoUsage()` immediately before the line you listed can guard against that.

Comment: Really you should aim to construct a [minimal test case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to address all of these uncertainties.